# Responsive background image in MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have followed advice from a number of posts on here but I cannot seem to get this to work for me. 
I am trying to have a background image on one page of my project that displays the full image and responds to the size of the browser window.

I have a bootstrap theme across the entire project (lumen, from Bootswatch) that is untouched, and have added the following code at the end of the css file to get this background image in my homepage, Index:

```
.index {
background-image:url('~/Content/images/home.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
}
```

I have also attempted to put #content after index, to no avail.

To load the image in my view, I have:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<body class="index">
</body>
```

However nothing happens for any of this. The image loads when I include

```
<body background="~/Content/images/home.jpg">
</body>
```

But it is incredibly zoomed in. I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction of a solution to this annoying problem.

Comment: Where have you defined the `.index` style? And does the url resolve correctly for `background-image:url('~/Content/images/home.jpg')`?

Comment: @Jasen I defined .index at the end of the main bootstrap css file that I'm using for my project. The image URL checks out fine!

Comment: Check your debug console again. Do you get 404 for the image url? I get 404 if the css url contains "~" where it won't get resolved to the application root.

Comment: @Jasen yes I am getting the 404 both when the css url contains "~" and when I remove  "~". 
When I have ".index {
background-image:url(/Content/images/home.jpg);", the error says 
"GET http://localhost:2081/Content/~/Content/images/home.jpg 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: @Jasen UPDATE: The below code is displaying the image, however it is very small and some is being hidden behind the navnar:

 .index {
background-image:url(/Content/images/home.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
}